# Yii2 AdminLTE installation error InvalidRepositoryException

Tags: yii2, typeahead.js, adminlte

I am using Yii2 and trying to install AdminLTE with the following command;

```
composer require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset "^2.1"
```

but I keep on getting this error

```
[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]                                                                                    
No valid bower.json was found in any branch or tag of https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js.git, could not load a package from it.
```

What should I do to resolve the above error?

Comment: Have you got fxp asset plugin installed or are you using asset packagist?

Comment: @Bizley thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I solved it by running the following command `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:dev-master"`

Comment: It's better to stick with [Asset Packagist](https://asset-packagist.org/) ;)